# using SOAP without a wsdl? php5

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

It appears i dont have a wsdl file but many xsd files. Can i do anything with SOAP or is a wsdl file required?

Answer (score 1):

The `SoapClient` class in PHP5 offers a non-wsdl mode according to [this documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), but I've never used it.  It appears to be possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can talk SOAP without a WSDL file, or even any xsd files, if you know all of the data types and function endpoints already.

If you have the XSD files, but are missing the WSDL file, you will need to find out the message names, their parameters, return values, and possible exceptions (faults). You will also, most importantly, need to find out the service port (URL) to connect to.

If you have all of that, you should be able to talk SOAP to the web service.